# how to import json to jsp

Tags: json, jsp

I have downloaded json-rpc-1.0 jar and this  is an example that I found in a web page

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

...
...

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("city", "Mumbai");
json.put("country", "India");

...

String output = json.toString();
```

I just wanna know how to import this jar to my jsp

I got something like this `<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject.*" %>`
but I don't have any idea of what I'm doing

Someone can tell me how it works this library? an easy example or a web page with docs about that

Answer (score 0):

As you in `*.java` file you import the class when you need. Same is applied in jsp pages. You can write the java code within `<% %>`. It works like you are writing the code in your servlet's method.

You can go through this page http://www.json.org/javadoc/ for `JSONObject` information and you can see http://www.jsptut.com/scriptlets.jsp for jsp's scriplets.

Comment: Better avoid scriptlets in jsp page [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: I agree ...He needed the guidance to understand the jsp.